# find new values in comma separated string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
       obj = ["30890560", "29092960", "28652336", "28642195", "26512957", "26190575", "25465297", "25144372", "23579449"]
```

and I need to compare it to a comma separated string

```
     "29092960,28652336,28642195,26512957,26190575,25465297,25144372"
```

is there a way for me to end up with an new comma separated string such as

```
       let newList = "30890560,23579449"
```

The array will always have more values then the string for the comparison.  This needs to be done using JavaScript inside a Vue.js page so no jQuery.

Do I need to split the comma separated string and compare each value in the array?

something like

```
        ["30890560", "29092960", "28652336", "28642195", "26512957", "26190575", "25465297", "25144372", "23579449"].includes('30890560');
```

Would a create a loop looking for a false value?  I would need some help to structure the loop.  Thanks

Comment: your explanation of what you want to achieve is not very clear.

Comment: *"is there a way"*. Yes, there is. You already seem to have some idea of what might be necessary -- splitting the string and comparing array values -- so give that a try and see what you come up with. Then if you get stuck, come back with a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem. Also take a look at [ask].

Comment: Define diff, is this `A-B`? You can covert both to array, compare and convert diff to comma separated string.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const arr1 = ["30890560", "29092960", "28652336", "28642195", "26512957", "26190575", "25465297", "25144372", "23579449"];
const str = "29092960,28652336,28642195,26512957,26190575,25465297,25144372";
const arr2 = str.split(','); // Convert CSV String to array

const res = arr1.filter(v => !arr2.includes(v));

console.log(res)
```

[String/split <sup><sub>MDN</sub></sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
[Array/filter <sup><sub>MDN</sub></sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
[Array/includes <sup><sub>MDN</sub></sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Thank you for your great answer.  People like you make StackOverflow great

Comment: @user1314159 blushing :) Glad to help and thank you for the kind comments to all the answers

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split, set and filter`

```js
const arr1 = ["30890560", "29092960", "28652336", "28642195", "26512957", "26190575", "25465297", "25144372", "23579449"]
const str = "29092960,28652336,28642195,26512957,26190575,25465297,25144372"
const arr2 = new Set(str.split(','))

const output = arr1.filter(v => !arr2.has(v));

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer.  People like you make StackOverflow great

Comment: @user1314159 always happy help :) you can mark as correct answer any of the answer which you feel has solved your problem in best way

Answer (score 1):

You can JavaScript's [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to separate the string into an array of strings. And then compare both the arrays.

```js
var obj = ["30890560", "29092960", "28652336", "28642195", "26512957", "26190575", "25465297", "25144372", "23579449"];

var str = "29092960,28652336,28642195,26512957,26190575,25465297,25144372";

var list = str.split(',');

console.log(list);

// Loop over two arrays to compare their equality.
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   if (list[i] !== obj[i]) {
     // Do something.
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to use one of the other solutions but your answer was very much appreciated .